# Phonegap Dynamic Updates

Tags: cordova

I have an app that I am building using Phonegap and Ripple. This isn't the the easiest way for me to test and make modifications to my app as I have to have Chrome open on a desktop. I'd like to be able to make changes and have this reflected on the app on my phone.

I know there is this: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fideanotion.net%2Fphonegaps-ability-dynamically-updating-mobile-app%2F&ei=9J_lUvrTOMHesASx-IG4Bw&usg=AFQjCNHGMzvAldrNy8DIikP2qP2F6c-KWw&sig2=N8KT0hmslpCH0Siq5Tw28Q, so it's possible to build and ship via API.

What would be the simplest method to dynamically update a PhoneGap app from server-side to app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as it sounds like, you're doing this for just testing, the easiest answer is going to be plugging your phone in, instead of a 'server-side to app' update. For iOS, this looks like:

1. Keep Xcode open, and a terminal tab open (in your app root directory)
2. Run 'cordova build ios' to update the application for iOS
3. Run the app in Xcode to open it on your phone

If you're using a git branch for your development, make sure you set Xcode to use that branch under 'Source Control -> YourAppName'.

If you need to quickly update a deployed app, then PhoneGap Build's 'Hydration' feature is your best option while testing. 
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/tools_hydration.md.html

With Hydration you can build a new application and it will be immediately updateable from the app itself.
Once you have a Hydration enabled app installed on your phone, the process can be:

1. Commit your code and push to your git repo
2. Grab a .zip of your repo (very easy with github)
3. Upload that .zip to Phonegap Build (Enter password and hit 'Build' manually if you have a passworded key)
4. Open the app on your phone and it will prompt you to update

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the cordova-cli you can plugin your device to your computer and make sure usb debugging is set on the device, then run:

```
cordova run android
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link resolves to:
http://ideanotion.net/phonegaps-ability-dynamically-updating-mobile-app/
..This is simply someone expounding and idea.

Sadly as yet there is no easy route to auto updates on PhoneGap hosted apps. I'd love to see a better answer. Try..

[GitHub - markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader: Remote update your Cordova app https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader ] ..too complex?

[GitHub - torrmal/cordova-standalone-hydration: This is a standalone hydration (app updater) script https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-standalone-hydration ] ..maybe?

[cordova-plugin-app-update https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-app-update ] Dubious