# Phonegap : Automated updating content

Tags: cordova

I have perhaps a simple question.

I am looking for a way to implement this:
[Phonegap Dynamic Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370920/phonegap-dynamic-updates)

but without using phonegap build, so just using phonegap. 
Any hints or examples out there that can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Use socket.IO and node JS. From server side make your node.js to provide api to update content and from client side make your socket.Io to keep track the server. You will get easily updates from server. Here is an example [socket.IO and Node.js chat application](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)